# Comparing text in cell with "=text" in another cell with excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to compare cell values in a loop with VBA. The loop that I was using was this

```
    For Each r In Rng
If Cells(r.Row, var1) = "string" And Cells(r.Row, var2) = Variable Then
    Cells(r.Row, var3) = "targetstring1"
ElseIf Cells(r.Row, var1) = "string2" And Cells(r.Row, var2) <> Variable Then
    Cells(r.Row, var3) = "targetstring2" 
end if
Next r
```

I am trying to allow inputting the conditions to an input sheet in the same excel workbook, but I need to make it dynamic. For example, in the input cells I want to put "=string" and "<>XX" where XX is the same value as Variable. This would allow the =/<> to be controlled from the input sheet instead of the code, and allow more flexibility for users to adapt the conditions to their situation.

Is this possible? I have tried to use the evaluate() function, but haven't been able to get it to work.

any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the first part of your if Statement work as you want ?

Answer (score 1):

Test Input:

[image: Test Input]

Code:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rw As Range

    For Each rw In Range("A2:C10").Rows
        If rw.Cells(1) <> "" Then
            rw.Cells(3).Value = Eval(rw.Cells(1), rw.Cells(2))
        End If
    Next rw

End Sub


Function Eval(rngVal As Range, rngCrit As Range)

    Dim addr As String, op As String
    addr = rngVal.Address(False, False)
    op = rngCrit.Value

    Eval = rngVal.Parent.Evaluate(addr & op)
End Function
```

Result:

[image: Output]

When entering criteria you may need to format your cells as Text or prepend `'` to prevent Excel from trying to treat it as a formula